# SQL Server Datetime Subquery Conversion Error?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting

Can't comprehend why when my subquery properly filters out bad date data (user entered in real query) but that the query fails when I cast the results of the subquery (which has clean dates) back to a datetime for the where clause.  I've included a tableless example which fails.  Spent a long time on this thus far - hating life.

```
select
 date_test
from 
(
 select
  date_test
 from 
 (
  select 
   '01/01/1980' as date_test
  union select 
   'a'
 ) as qry_bad_date
 where
  ISDATE(date_test) = 1
) as qry_only_valid_date
where
 cast(date_test as datetime) = '01/01/1980'
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Query Analyzer, go to the Query menu and select 'Display estimated execution plan', or hit CTRL+L.  Sql Server's query optimizer has decided that comparing date_test to your specified date belongs higher on the food chain.  If you add the ISDATE check to your where clause it works fine:

```
select date_test 
from (select date_test
        from (select '1980/01/01' as date_test
                union
                select 'a'
            ) as qry_bad_date 
        where ISDATE(date_test) = 1
    ) as qry_only_valid_date 
where ISDATE(date_test) = 1 and cast(date_test as datetime) = '1980/01/01'
```

If you use temp tables or table variables to force the queries to execute separately it also works:

```
declare @dt1 table (date_test varchar(20))
declare @dt2 table (date_test varchar(20))
insert @dt1 select '1980/01/01' union select 'a'
insert @dt2 select date_test from @dt1 where ISDATE(date_test) = 1
select date_test
from @dt2
where cast(date_test as datetime) = '1980/01/01'
```

Comment: Can't use temp tables as this SQL lives inside scaler UDf...  But the where clause does work!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works too.  Thanks for all the help!

```
select
    date_test
from 
(
    select
        case isdate(date_test) when 1 then CAST(date_test  as datetime) else null end as date_test
    from 
    (
        select 
            '1980/01/01' as date_test
        union select 
            'a'
    ) as qry_bad_date
    where
        ISDATE(date_test) = 1
) as qry_only_valid_date
where
    cast(date_test as datetime) = '1980/01/01'
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!