# nested SELECT statements interact in ways that I don't understand

Tags: t-sql

I thought I understood how I can do a `SELECT` from the results of another `SELECT` statement, but there seems to be some sort of blurring of scope that I don't understand.  I am using  SQL Server 2008R2.

It is easiest to explain with an example.

Create a table with a single nvarchar column - load the table with a single text value and a couple of numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable( a nvarchar(30) ); 
INSERT INTO #temptable( a )
    VALUES('apple');
INSERT INTO #temptable( a )
    VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO #temptable( a )
    VALUES(2);

select * from #temptable;
```

This will return:  `apple, 1, 2`

Use `IsNumeric` to get only the rows of the table that can be cast to numeric - this will leave the text value `apple` behind.  This works fine.

```
    select cast(a as int) as NumA
    from #temptable 
    where IsNumeric(a) = 1 ;
```

This returns: `1, 2`

However, if I use that exact same query as an inner select, and try to do a numeric `WHERE` clause, it fails saying cannot convert `nvarchar` value 'apple' to data type `int`.  How has it got the value 'apple' back??

```
    select 
        x.NumA
    from 
    (
        select cast(a as int) as NumA
        from #temptable 
        where IsNumeric(a) = 1 
    ) x
    where x.NumA > 1
    ;
```

Note that the failing query works just fine without the `WHERE` clause:

```
    select 
        x.NumA
    from 
    (
        select cast(a as int) as NumA
        from #temptable 
        where IsNumeric(a) = 1 
    ) x
    ;
```

I find this very surprising.  What am I not getting? TIA

Comment: fyi, this also works:select 
        x.NumA, case when (x.NumA > 1) then 1 else 0 end as gt1

Comment: found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384709/sql-server-datetime-subquery-conversion-error

Comment: Thanks Beth, I missed that previous question

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the estimated execution plan you'll find that it has optimized the inner query into the outer and combined the `WHERE` clauses.

Using a CTE to isolate the operations works (in SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
declare @temptable as table ( a nvarchar(30) );  
INSERT INTO @temptable( a ) 
    VALUES ('apple'), ('1'), ('2'); 

with Numbers as (    
  select cast(a as int) as NumA 
    from @temptable  
      where IsNumeric(a) = 1  
  )
  select * from Numbers
```

Comment: That is **not** guaranteed to work either. See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) The only safe pattern (ignoring possible issues with `isnumeric` itself) is `select case when IsNumeric(a) = 1 then cast(a as int) end as NumA` (or `try-convert` if on 2012)

Comment: If you add the missing `where NumA > 1` to your query you will likely find it breaks again.

Comment: @Martin, you are quite correct - adding the where clause causes the same error to come up.  However, this post (and stackoverflow.com/questions/4384709/) have answered my question - it is the fact that the optimizer is combining the queries instead of handling them in sequence.  There are lots of ways I can re-write my code to get the desired result, I just didn't understand what was happening.  Oh and  per my original post I am on SS2008R2.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this is fair and simple. When a query is executed there are some steps that are being followed. This is a parse, algebrize, optimize and compile. 
The algebrize part in this case will get all the objects you need for this query. The optimize will use these objects to create a best query plan which will be compiled and executed...

So, when you look into that part you will see it will do a table scan on #temptable. And #temptable is defined as the way you created your table. That you will do some compute on it is a different thing..... The column still has the nvarchar datatype..

To know how this works you have to know how to read a query. First all the objects are retrieved (from table, inner join table), then the predicates (where, on), then the grouping and such, then the select of the columns (with the cast) and then the orderby.

So with that in mind, when you have a combination of selects, the optimizer will still process it that way.. since your select is subordinate to the from and join parts of your query, it will be a reason for getting this error.

I hope i made it a little clear?

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer is free to move expressions in the query plan in order to produce the most cost efficient plan for retrieving the data (the evaluation order of the predicates is not guaranteed). I think using the case expression like bellow produces a NULL in absence of the ELSE clause and thus takes the APPLE out

select a from #temptable where  case when isnumeric(a) = 1 then a end > 1