# SQL Server Convert Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is a very weird issue I'm facing.  When I run the following query:

```
select p1.*  
from art_asset as p0 
inner join  
   (select   
       t0.art_asset_id as Id, t0.Host, 
       convert(INT, substring(t0.host, len(rtrim(t0.host)) -1 , 2)) as Number    
    from art_asset t0   
    where t0.manufacturer = 'McAfee' and decommissioned = 0) as p1 on p1.Id = p0.art_asset_id
```

I get 3 columns back and everything looks exactly like I would suspect it to look. I get an `Id` column, a `Host` column, and a `Number` column.

However, when I add a where clause to the end of this query like below:

```
select p1.*  
from art_asset as p0 
inner join  
   (select
       t0.art_asset_id as Id, t0.Host, 
       convert(INT, substring(t0.host, len(rtrim(t0.host)) -1 , 2)) as Number    
    from art_asset t0   
    where t0.manufacturer = 'McAfee' and decommissioned = 0 ) as p1 on p1.id = p0.art_asset_id
where p1.Number <> 1
```

I get the following error!?!

> *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1Z' to data type int.*

Here is a sample of the data:

```
| Id    | Host                | Number |
----------------------------------------
| 1     | DEVICENAME80        | 80     |
| 2     | DEVICENAME81        | 81     |
| 3     | DEVICENAME60        | 60     |
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just join on the table itself instead of that select statement? What does only running the select statement in the parenthesis give you?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I tried putting the convert() in the where clause and filtering on that and it gave me the same error. I noticed that it working the select statement, so I thought I'd try just making it a subselect and see if that would work.  Neither worked.

Comment: I really don't want to convert this number, but I need to filter on devices with numbers between certain values.  So this was the only way I could think to do it.

Comment: If you are going to be running this often, have you considered just adding another column to the table where you store the number?

Comment: I don't control the data, so that is not an option.

Comment: What happens if you run my query below with no CONVERT function? Just the SUBSTRING (and implicit conversion will take care of it)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to cast value as float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192524/unable-to-cast-value-as-float)

Comment: So each host always has two digit number? Otherwise your CONVERT could run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

[CONVERT in where clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) works, so your original query should work:

```
SELECT
  art_asset_id as Id, 
  Host, 
  CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(host, len(rtrim(host)) -1 , 2)) as Number    
FROM art_asset  
WHERE manufacturer = 'McAfee'
  AND decommissioned = 0
  AND CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(host, len(rtrim(host)) -1 , 2)) <> 1
```

But since you said this CONVERT statement is failing, a WHERE clause that utilizes [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) will also work:

```
WHERE manufacturer = 'McAfee'
  AND decommissioned = 0
  AND SUBSTRING(host, len(rtrim(host)) -1 , 2) <> 1
```

Comment: Really? a revange down vote? I know you're from Texas but... hold it cowboy, why are not rivals.

Comment: Sorry, that was not a revenge down vote. Your "answer" did not tell him the answer, you merely told him it was wrong. The other guy told him how to fix it. So I voted his up.

Comment: As I said you're childish. 1. I tested it and it didn't work. 2. There is nothing in the OP question mentioning he's using asp.net which only it has server controls. 3. IF it would have work and the OP stated he's using Asp.Net I would still not suggest using that solution as it misuse the `runat="server'` for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the convert is getting optimized to run when you don't want it to.
check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384709/sql-server-datetime-subquery-conversion-error)

Comment: I tried something like that but it didn't seem to fail.  http://codepaste.net/3w28hx

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your where clause to:

```
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(p1.Number)=1 AND p1.Number <> 1
```