# Can't use BETWEEN for SQL Server dates

Tags: sql-server, date, casting

I'm having an excruciating time with `yyyymmdd` dates. In this DB, `null` dates are stored as empty string.

This executes just fine and I can manually check there are no badness in the dates

```
SELECT 
    effective, expiration 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CONVERT(date, date_effective, 112) as effective,
         CONVERT(date, date_expiration, 112) as expiration
     FROM ... ) AS X
```

But then when I want to compare them like so:

```
...
) AS X
WHERE 
    GETDATE() BETWEEN effective AND expiration
```

this throws an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I am drowning and have spent hours trying to get this date conversion to work. I fear my only alternative is to stick what I want into a temp table. Date conversion should not be this hard. Please help me convert these dates and be able to compare them.

EDIT: There are DIRTY rows in this very large database, 0.003% of the rows are bad

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't have any "dirty" rows, i.e. ones that don't nicely fit into the yyyymmdd or empty string pattern?

Comment: I cannot and I suspect this is the case. I'm going to work on it a little

Comment: @SqlOnly BINGO there is dirty data, how do I deal?

Comment: @SqlOnly I would be happy to accept your comment as an answer, I was able to make a CASE statement around the length of the string

Comment: Date conversion should be this hard... it is hard.  Especially when the input data is bad.

Comment: @rlb.usa see below [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39151116/6415885) and thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact data type of your date strings (varchar, nvarchar, length, etc.), it's tough to prescribe a perfect solution.  Your question (and possible solution) is also very similar to [SO 4384709](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384709/sql-server-datetime-subquery-conversion-error).  Given those caveats, I would pursue a temp table solution (see "@tblCleanDatesAndThings"), as below.

```
--Define a table structure for debugging
DECLARE @tblDatesAndThings TABLE
    (
    date_effective varchar(100) NULL
    ,date_expiration varchar(100) NULL
    )

--Insert some test data
INSERT INTO @tblDatesAndThings
    SELECT '',''  --Bad data (per original question)
    UNION SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE())), CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(d,1, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(d, -2, GETDATE())), CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(d, 2, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT 'a', 'b'  --Bad data (per later edit/comment)

--Define a table structure for clean (or pre-processed) data in our preferred data/output type
DECLARE @tblCleanDatesAndThings TABLE
    (
    date_effective date
    , date_expiration date
    )

--Gather our cleaned up data
INSERT INTO @tblCleanDatesAndThings
    SELECT date_effective,
        date_expiration
    FROM @tblDatesAndThings
        WHERE ISDATE(date_effective) = 1
        AND ISDATE(date_expiration)  = 1

--Apply our criteria to the clean data, for final output
SELECT * FROM @tblCleanDatesAndThings
    WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN date_effective AND date_expiration
```

Answer (score 1):

since your `effective` and `expiration` is in string YYYYMMDD, you only need to convert `GETDATE()` to that format and compare. And no convertion required on the `effective` and `expiration` column

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) BETWEEN  effective AND expiration
```

by the way, you should consider using date or datetime data type for these 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server might be getting confused because you're trying to compare a `DATE` to a `DATETIME`, since `GETDATE()` returns the latter.  Try changing your conversions so you're using `datetime`, like this:

```
CONVERT(datetime, date_effective, 112) as effective
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare to the unconverted values -- like this

```
SELECT effective, expiration 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(date, date_effective, 112) as effective,
        CONVERT(date, date_expiration, 112) as expiration,
         date_effective, date_expiration
    FROM ...
) AS X
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN date_effective AND date_expiration
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(date, date_effective, 112) as effective,
CONVERT(date, date_expiration, 112) as expiration
FROM ..
WHERE ISDATE(date_effective) and ISDATE(date_expiration)
```